# How to Redirect a URL based on query string located in the middle of the url?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

this .htaccess rule works for url ending with the "format=pdf" query string but not if its in the middle of the url.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^format=pdf$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.betonbetone.co.il/404?  [R=301,L]
```

works: `http://www.mysite.com/index.php/floor/230-1?format=pdf`

doesn't work: `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?view=article&catid=37%3A2009-10-15-19-28-33&id=81%3A2009-09-21-21-00-34&format=pdf&option=com_content&Itemid=89`

can some one help to make it work for the second url ?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some regex manipulation:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)format=pdf(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule $ http://www.betonbetone.co.il/404?  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You're most welcome, glad that it worked out for you.